# Collective Risk Model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

As an acturial student, I have to do :

Show that for any two random variables V, W one has

Var(W) = E(Var(W|V )) + Var(E(W|V )).

Use the formula to solve the following problem: In a tourist office trips are organized
at days with sunny weather only. Assume that on each day the weather is sunny
with probability 0.7, independent of the other days. If a new guide starts to work on
a sunny day, and if this guide faces N consecutive sunny days, the total number of
customers until the first non-sunny day is Poisson distributed with parameter 5N,
what is the expectation and variance of total customers that this guide faces until
the first non-sunny day?

Is it right to use a geometric distribution for the sunny or non-sunny day ? If not which one do I need to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of the total variance equation, take
$$
Var(W) = E[W^2] - E^2[W],
$$
by using the law of total expectation 
$$
Var(W) = E[E[W^2|X]] - (E[E[W|X]])^2= E[Var(W|X) + E^2[W|X]] - (E[E[W|X]])^2,
$$
slightly rearranging the equation you'll get the formula 
\begin{align}
Var(W) = & E[Var(W|X)] + E( E^2[W|X]) - (E[E[W|X]])^2\\
       = & E[Var(W|X)] + Var[E(W|X)] \, . 
\end{align}

For the second part, denote $N$ the number of consecutive sunny day, that is $N \sim Geo(0.3)$ and the number of costumers $X$ each day $i$ is $Poisson(5)$, thus
$$
E(\sum_{i=1}^NX_i) =EX_i EN=\frac{5}{0.3}.
$$
For the variance, use the law of total variance that you proved in the first part.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the parameter of the Poisson is 5N ? We can use a constant instead a random parameter ? I have used 0.3 instead of 0.7. Could you explain me how do you choose your parameter of the Geometric distribution ?

Comment: 2) Sorry, it is $0.3$ indeed. I've changed the answer. 1) It $5N$ for $N$ day, hence $5$ for each day and $E(5N) = 5EN=EXEN=5/0.3$.